# Javadoc method signatures are wrong

Tags: java, android, ant, javadoc

I have an Android library that I am compiling with ant and obfuscating with ProGuard. When I include the library to use in another project and view the autocomplete info, I see some of the parameter names are in the wrong order (although the types are correct).

So far I have only seen this on Eclipse - intelliJ is preserving the correct param name order.

For example, I have a library function:

```
public void blah(String a, String b, boolean c, boolean d)
```

If I view the Javadoc reference in Eclipse by calling in my test project:

```
com.mylibrary.bl
```

it will autocomplete with something like:

```
blah(String b, String c, boolean d, boolean a)
```

So the names are wrong and users could end up putting the wrong values in.
What could be causing this?

I also noticed that if I directly export to jar without using ant, the signatures are correct.

Comment: Um. You obfuscated the code. What did you expect? The javadoc generator isn't psychic. Generate the javadoc before you mangle the code.

Comment: I am using -keepparameternames so knowing the names isn't a problem. However, found this question someone else asked which appears to be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656447/weird-behaviour-while-obfuscating-a-jar-with-proguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [Weird behaviour while obfuscating a JAR with proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656447/weird-behaviour-while-obfuscating-a-jar-with-proguard)

Looks like a ProGuard 4.7 and under issue, I will update my version.

Comment: Confirmed, this fixes it!